# Transform Keil5 C Project to C++ Project Error with the Interrupt Function

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, startup, keil

After I transform the Project from C to C++, the program is seem to be stuck in the interrupt function.

I've wrote a keil embedded project with C, and then I tried to write it with C++. Then I found the program was stuck in the interrupt function even I write the IRQHandler functions properly (they do work in C project).
The USART1 will be stuck meanwhile the CAN receive/transmit are still working.

```
// this is the USART_IRQHandler   

void USART1_IRQHandler(void)      
{
    if(USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET)   
    {                                                                        
        USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interrupt handlers require C linkage if using C++ compilation:

```
extern "C" void USART1_IRQHandler(void)      
{
    if(USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET)   
    {                                                                        
        USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE);
    }
}
```

Without C linkage the function `USART1_IRQHandler` will not replace the default handler of the same name but with C linkage which is an endless-loop, hence it appears to be "*stuck in the interrupt function*", which it is... just a different interrupt function.

The C linkage prevents C++ "name mangling" that otherwise causes the symbol to not be the same as the interrupt handler weak-link symbol name.